# query the rownumber and query the content with limit fail

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two functions in the model, both of which queires the same thing, except that the second one requires a Limit of number and offset in the query string. I call both in the controller but only the first function does what I want, the second return 0

```
public function get_row_nums()
    {
        $commenttb="commenttb";
        $membertb="membertb";
        $query=sprintf("SELECT `%s`.* FROM `%s` JOIN `%s` ON (`%s`.userid=`%s`.userid)",
               $commenttb,
               $commenttb,
               $membertb,
               $commenttb,
               $membertb);
        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        print_r($query->result_array());
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    public function get_comments($num,$offset)
    {
        $commenttb="commenttb";
        $membertb="membertb";
        $query=sprintf("SELECT `%s`.* FROM `%s` JOIN `%s` ON (`%s`.userid=`%s`.userid) LIMIT %d,%d",
               $commenttb,
               $commenttb,
               $membertb,
               $commenttb,
               $membertb,
               $num,
               $offset);

        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        print_r($query->result_array());
        return $query;
    }
```

And here is the function in teh controller

```
public function get_comments()
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/blog/list_comment_view.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }
        else
        {
            $userid=$this->get_userid();
            $row_nums=$this->blog->get_row_nums();
            $config['base_url']=base_url().'index.php/blog/list_comment_view';
            $config['total_rows']=$row_nums;
            print_r($row_nums);
            $config['per_page']=5;
            $config['num_links']=2;
            $config['full_tag_open']='<p>';
            $config['full_tag_close']='<p>';
            $config['first_link']='First';
            $config['last_link']='Last';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['comments']=$this->blog->get_comments($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
            $this->load->library('table');
            $this->table->set_heading('No','Title','Created','Modified','Action');
            $this->load->view('blog/list_comment_view', $data);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to check it again and again but I don't know still where teh possible mistake I might have made in the source code that the view loaded only print Array() on the second call to the second function of the model. I am grateful for any help.

**UPDATE:**
I setup my base_url in config file to point to http://localhost/CodeIgniter/
and I also created a folder in Controller named Blog where I store all stuff.
I reset my default route "/blog/LoginClassName";
Everything works fine up to this part.

Comment: What is the value of `$this->uri->segment(3)` and what does the generated query look like? You really should have some error checking on those query calls. Database queries don't always succeed, you know, even if the query string is syntactically perfect.

Comment: what does $config['per_page'] and $this->uri->segment(3) print. I am pretty sure Either one of them is wrong

Comment: what is result of `echo $query;` before you execute it

Comment: SELECT `commenttb`.* FROM `commenttb` JOIN `membertb` ON (`commenttb`.userid=`membertb`.userid) LIMIT 5,0

Comment: please wait, I am having lunch

Comment: I am glad that you respect your peers :). anyway whats for lunch?

Answer (score 0):

proper LIMIT systax is

```
 LIMIT OFFSET,LIMIT
```

So your query **should** look like this

```
 SELECT commenttb.* FROM commenttb JOIN membertb ON (commenttb.userid=membertb.userid) LIMIT 0,5
```

which means change your $query to this

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT `%s`.* FROM `%s` JOIN `%s` ON (`%s`.userid=`%s`.userid) LIMIT %d,%d",
           $commenttb,
           $commenttb,
           $membertb,
           $commenttb,
           $membertb,
           $offset,
           $num);
```